# The move function is not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, p5.js

I am having trouble with this project. I’m pretty new on this and I doesn’t know why this piece of code is not working properly.
There is a spot in the grid (you, the player) that is transferred to another position if certain conditions happen. Here, if dir equals to 1 or 2 (right or down) the player moves totally to that direction.

[PHOTO: This is how the sprite should move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUNCN.jpg)

[PHOTO: This is how it moves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE1AL.jpg)

Here is a link to the p5 web editor:
https://editor.p5js.org/MarcoGaLo/full/cU2K72dRZ

And this is the piece of code that doesn’t work:

```
//dir is 0 when up arrow is pressed, 1 with right arrow, 2 down, 3 for left
  move() {
    if (dir == 0 && !grid[this.i][this.j - 1].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i][this.j - 1].box) {
        if (!grid[this.i][this.j - 2].wall && !grid[this.i][this.j - 2].box) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i][this.j - 1].player = true;
          grid[this.i][this.j - 2].box = true;
          grid[this.i][this.j - 1].box = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i][this.j - 1].player = true;
      }
    }
    
    if (dir == 1 && !grid[this.i + 1][this.j].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i + 1][this.j].box) {
        if (!grid[this.i + 2][this.j].wall && !grid[this.i + 2][this.j].box) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i + 1][this.j].player = true;
          grid[this.i + 2][this.j].box = true;
          grid[this.i + 1][this.j].box = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i + 1][this.j].player = true;
      }
    }
    
    if (dir == 2 && !grid[this.i][this.j + 1].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i][this.j + 1].box) {
        if (!grid[this.i][this.j + 2].wall && !grid[this.i][this.j + 2].box) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i][this.j + 1].player = true;
          grid[this.i][this.j + 2].box = true;
          grid[this.i][this.j + 1].box = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i][this.j + 1].player = true;
      }
    }
    if (dir == 3 && !grid[this.i - 1][this.j].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i - 1][this.j].box) {
        if (!grid[this.i - 2][this.j].wall && !grid[this.i - 2][this.j].box) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i - 1][this.j].player = true;
          grid[this.i - 2][this.j].box = true;
          grid[this.i - 1][this.j].box = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i - 1][this.j].player = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please explain what you want us to do. Also we don't need to see your entire code to be able to fix one aspect of it.

Comment: Ok. Now it’s fixed and corrected

Comment: Funny thing is the piece that you showed did work...

Comment: I use Chrome in an iPad and it doesn’t work. May I trie on a computer?

Comment: It was another section of code that was buggy. Not the one you showed after revision.

Comment: I don't understand you. Haven't you answered my question below? Although I would say it makes no difference. So, which is the buggy section???

Comment: No, as I said bellow. The problem was not the `move()` function but the `keypressed()` function. You forgot the `return` call. The simplified `move()` function I created was a side project :)

Comment: I have rewritten the code using return in my code and in yours and it is still buggy. Have you tried it? I now understand why it was buggy but for some reason it doesn't work. Could you paste a link to the editor in case it works for you?? Thanks for all!

Comment: Have you seen my comments on your answer?

Comment: its working fine for me (sorry for late response)

Comment: I don't know what happens but (without changing nothing) it works now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the when you itterate throught all the grid squares to find the player cell you keep itterating through finding the player. So the the player is found and moved and then you search the next area that has the player, so move it again (until it reaches the walls). The fix is just adding a return statement in the keypressed function. I'll add a workable code block here.

```js
let grid = [];
var player;
var w = 40;
var dir,
  nivel = 1;
let up, down, right, left;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    grid[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
      grid[i][j] = new Cell(i * w, j * w, i, j);
    }
  }
  up = createButton("⬆");
  up.position(70, height + 10);
  down = createButton("⬇");
  down.position(70, height + 70);
  right = createButton("➡");
  right.position(130, height + 40);
  left = createButton("⬅");
  left.position(10, height + 40);
  reset = createButton("RESET")
  reset.position(260, height + 40)
  level(nivel);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
      grid[i][j].show();
    }
  }
  up.mousePressed(botonUp);
  down.mousePressed(botonDown);
  right.mousePressed(botonRight);
  left.mousePressed(botonLeft);
  reset.mousePressed(resetear)
}

function resetear() {
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
        grid[i][j].reset();
    }
  }
}

function botonUp() {
  dir = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j].player) {
        grid[i][j].move();
      }
    }
  }
}
function botonRight() {
  dir = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j].player) {
        grid[i][j].move();
      }
    }
  }
}
function botonDown() {
  dir = 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j].player) {
        grid[i][j].move();
      }
    }
  }
}

function botonLeft() {
  dir = 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j].player) {
        grid[i][j].move();
      }
    }
  }
}

function keyPressed() {
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
      if (keyCode == 82) {
        resetear();
      }
      if (grid[i][j].player) {
        if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
          dir = 0;
        }
        if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
          dir = 1;
        }
        if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
          dir = 2;
        }
        if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
          dir = 3;
        }
        grid[i][j].move();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

function level(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < width / w; i++) {
    grid[0][i].wall = true;
    grid[width / w - 1][i].wall = true;
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < height / w; j++) {
    grid[j][0].wall = true;
    grid[j][height / w - 1].wall = true;
  }
  if (n == 1) {
    grid[4][4].caja = true;
    grid[4][7].player = true;
    grid[2][4].wall = true;
    grid[3][5].wall = true;
    grid[7][6].spot = true;
  } else if (n == 2) {
  }
}

class Cell {
  constructor(x, y, i, j) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.w = w;
    this.caja = false;
    this.player = false;
    this.wall = false;
    this.spot = false;
    this.time = 0;
  }

  show() {
    if (this.caja) {
      fill("brown");
      stroke(57, 0, 8);
      strokeWeight(3);
      rect(this.x + 2.5, this.y + 2.5, w - 5, w - 5);
      line(this.x + 2.5, this.y + 2.5, this.x + w - 2.5, this.y + w - 2.5);
      line(this.x + w - 2.5, this.y + 2.5, this.x + 2.5, this.y + w - 2.5);
    } else {
      fill(255);
      strokeWeight(1);
      stroke(0, 50);
      rect(this.x, this.y, w, w);
    }
    if (this.player) {
      ellipseMode(CORNER);
      fill(0);
      circle(this.x + 3, this.y + 3, w - 6);
    } else if (this.spot) {
      if (this.time % 45 > 15) {
        fill(104, 252, 3);
        noStroke();
        circle(this.x + 2, this.y + 2, w - 4);
      }
    } else if (this.wall) {
      fill(130);
      rect(this.x, this.y, w, w);
    }
    if (this.caja && this.spot) nivel++;
    this.time++;
    if (this.time == 4500) {
      this.time = 0;
    }
  }

  move() {
    if (dir == 0 && !grid[this.i][this.j - 1].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i][this.j - 1].caja) {
        if (!grid[this.i][this.j - 2].wall && !grid[this.i][this.j - 2].caja) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i][this.j - 1].player = true;
          grid[this.i][this.j - 2].caja = true;
          grid[this.i][this.j - 1].caja = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i][this.j - 1].player = true;
      }
    }
    
    if (dir == 1 && !grid[this.i + 1][this.j].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i + 1][this.j].caja) {
        if (!grid[this.i + 2][this.j].wall && !grid[this.i + 2][this.j].caja) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i + 1][this.j].player = true;
          grid[this.i + 2][this.j].caja = true;
          grid[this.i + 1][this.j].caja = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i + 1][this.j].player = true;
      }
    }
    
    if (dir == 2 && !grid[this.i][this.j + 1].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i][this.j + 1].caja) {
        if (!grid[this.i][this.j + 2].wall && !grid[this.i][this.j + 2].caja) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i][this.j + 1].player = true;
          grid[this.i][this.j + 2].caja = true;
          grid[this.i][this.j + 1].caja = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i][this.j + 1].player = true;
      }
    }
    if (dir == 3 && !grid[this.i - 1][this.j].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i - 1][this.j].caja) {
        if (!grid[this.i - 2][this.j].wall && !grid[this.i - 2][this.j].caja) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i - 1][this.j].player = true;
          grid[this.i - 2][this.j].caja = true;
          grid[this.i - 1][this.j].caja = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i - 1][this.j].player = true;
      }
    }
  }

  reset() {
    this.caja = false;
    this.player = false;
    this.wall = false;
    this.spot = false;
    this.time = 0;
    level(nivel);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

I also started on a new move function that is REALLY simplified:

```
move() {
  
    let m = 0;
  
    switch(dir){
        
      case 0: m = -1; break;
      case 1: m =  1; break;
      case 2: m =  1; break;
      case 3: m = -1; break;
      default: throw new Error("dir not 0 - 3");
      
    }
  
    let d = (dir == 0 || dir == 2);
  
    if (!grid[this.i + !d * m][this.j + d * m].wall) {
      if (grid[this.i + !d * m][this.j + d * m].box) {
        if (!grid[this.i + !d * m * 2][this.j + d * m * 2].wall && !grid[this.i + !d * m * 2][this.j + d * m * 2].box) {
          this.player = false;
          grid[this.i + !d * m][this.j + d * m].player = true;
          grid[this.i + !d * m * 2][this.j + d * m * 2].box = true;
          grid[this.i + !d * m][this.j + d * m].box = false;
        }
      } else {
        this.player = false;
        grid[this.i + !d * m][this.j + d * m].player = true;
      }
    }
  
  }
```

Although I can't get the box collision to work. I don't quite understand how it's suppose to work (in the code).

Comment: I will try it on a computer as soon as possible (I am on iPad on Chrome), but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Regarding the new function move() thanks, I would implement it when I finish understanding it .

Comment: To make the movement of the player and the box I thought about changing properties of each spot on the array/grid. For example, I look on the properties of the next spot. If it is empty (this.wall = false,  this.caja = false), then the properties are swapped. If there is a box and no wall on the next to spots: grid[this.i][this.j + 2].wall = false (in case it moves right), the box and the player will change properties with the spot on the right. I hope I answered your doubts. THANKS!!!

Comment: Hello again! How do you make that code snippet??

Comment: I was meaning about writing code using the stack snippets. Sorry for bothering you, but don’t you worry, I now know